# What does 0/0 do the css background property?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm trying use the following style:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,orange,orange) 0 0/0 100% no-repeat, rgba(255, 165, 0,0.1);
```

This is within a custom semantic theme which when I build is **breaking** when compiling as:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(orange), to(orange)) 0 NaN 100% no-repeat, rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1);
```

Notice the **NaN**

What is the 0/0 doing?
Is there another way to code this to prevent the compile issues w semantic custom themes?

Comment: did you also try 0px or 0% like i suggested in the other answer :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Docs on the background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), that is position/background-size:

> The  value may only be included immediately after , separated with the '/' character, like this: "center/80%".

You could remove that `0/0` and add the lines:

```
background-size: 0;
background-position: 0;
```

if it was necessary.

Comment: If the background-size and background-position properties work without declaring units for attributes then why does this work (https://jsfiddle.net/Lum0do4f/3/) but this doesn’t (https://jsfiddle.net/3nm6tc7d/3/)?

Answer (score 0):

0/0 isn’t valid in CSS as it calculates to NaN, you can’t divide zero by zero. This is true both in CSS “calc” and in extentsion like SaSS.

You need to declare real values for background-position and background-size, you can do this with absolute or relative units, or by using keywords (ie. “Right”, “left”, “center”).

Also note : “0 0” isn’t valid, it essentially mean nothing so your image will render as if you didn’t declare a value (upper-left corner is the default). You must use a unit indicator.

Comment: I thought CSS doesn't evaluate mathematical expressions that aren't in `calc`. Also your answer seems to be ignoring that units (eg. `px`, `em`, `vw`) are a valid alternative to percentages. Additionally, cardinal edge positions (eg.`left`, `top`) aren't necessarily "defaults".

Comment: True and true. CSS doesn’t do math outside of calc, but it looks like OP was asking about compiling (ie. SaSS or SCSS) and extensions will often take care of math for you, which is likely why NaN is present. Also, you’re right about “defaults”—I’ll update to make this more semantic, should be “keyword”.

Comment: 0/0 _is_ valid in the background shorthand, see my answer.

Comment: No, it’s not. The W3 specs (https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position) don’t list values without units indicators as valid, you have to use a unit or keyword.

Comment: @JDP I appreciate the reference to w3.org, but in fact a zero without units is the preferred way to use zeros. In fact, css linters will often mark warnings if you _use_ units with a zero.

Comment: 0/0 still isn’t value though, it’s clear that OP’s compiler is throwing NaN. 0 without units is a great way to declare nothing, but in this case it’s causing issues with the compiling (ie. “What is the 0/0 doing?”).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, neither of the current answers are answering your questions well. Here’s a more concise breakdown:

**Q: What does 0/0 in CSS background property do?** 
 
A: It defines the properties for `background-position` and `background-size` when using `background` shorthand.

**Q: ...Notice the NaN, what is the 0/0 doing?** 
A: It looks like your compiler is trying to calculate 0/0. Mathematically you can’t  divide zero by zero, so your compiler is throwing out NaN (not a number) to let you know there’s an error.

**Q: Is there another way to code this to prevent the compiler issues...**
A: Since you’re setting background-position to it’s default you can use the keywords `top right` or `initial`. This should help avoid any potential calculations from being executed, ex:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,orange,orange) top right/0% 100% no-repeat rgba(255, 165, 0,0.1);
```